# color overlay png in html5/css3

Tags: html, css, colors, png

I have a lot of png-images, and now I want to change their color. I could open all these images in photoshop and add a Layer style - Color Overlay.

For example:
http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/103303/128/arrow_right_sans_icon
*Change the black color to gray.*

**But is there an easy way to do this with HTML5/CSS3?**

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css

Comment: I could do this, but then I have to change all these png-images. I was wondering if I could change the color without adapting the images in Photoshop.

Comment: I know the jQuery Mobile project is doing something similar. I'm not sure how, but it might be worth investigating. If you find a html5/css3 solution to this problem, please let us (SO) know.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with just CSS but has so major limitations it's far from a perfect solution.

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/arrow_sans_right-128.png"/>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0,.4), rgba(0, 0, 0,.4));
}
```

The limitations being

- Webkit only
- Can only change black to something more transparent, i.e. grey. Colour masks are not possible.

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K4AtR/) - *Tested in Chrome 26.*

Answer (score 3):

(A bit late)

If you know the background will remain the same color throughout the entire website and you don't mind messing around a bit in Photoshop, you could of course fill the transparent part with your background color and cut out the icon to make that part transparent.

That way you can place a background color behind it and make it whatever color you want...

**HTML**

```
<img src="transparencyswitch.png" height="20" width="20"/>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting your PNG into a SVG. I had the same problem, till I did that. From there, you only have to change the fill color (which can also be dynamic for, for example, wordpress)

Answer (score -2):

A way of doing this is to put the image in a div and put a div above that with opacity so you still can see the image a little bit but it has the color of the overlaying div.
Other ways aren't possible with html5/css3.

examples: [here](http://www.zenelements.com/blog/css3-hsl-hsla-color-opacity/)

Comment: Examples link deaded.