# Apply color overlay to picture in HTML pages

Tags: html, css

I have a PNG picture representing a monochrome white magnifying glass with an alpha channel. This image is overlayed on the top of other pictures, with a semi-transparent background such that you still see below it:

[image: Picture with a magnifying glass overlay]

When you hover that picture, I would like it to change to red, as do textual links per my CSS.

I have considered several options:

- Use a [`'LEFT-POINTING MAGNIFYING GLASS' (U+1F50D)` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50d/index.htm). This wouldn't work for the (fewer and fewer) clients that don't support an extensive set of Unicode characters; but when it works, it's not guaranteed to produce a monochrome character (on Apple implementations, it's a full-color emoji).
- Use a mask, as [described in this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css). This only works when you don't mind an opaque background (mine is **not** opaque) or when you can tell what's underneath your element with great certainty (and then it's rather hackish and ugly).

My current solution is to use a different picture to represent the white magnifying glass and the red magnifying glass that it changes for when you hover over the picture. It's an okay solution, but I was wondering if there was a way I could have just one picture of just one color, so that I don't have to go back to change the image color if I change my mind about the color.

I'm already doing extensive use of CSS3 and HTML5, so I don't mind going deeper as long as it's supported by the latest iterations of each major browser.

Comment: Have you considered using SVG instead of a PNG? You could adjust the `fill` property on the fly with CSS.

Comment: @lukiffer, I guess I could, but it's not a vector image (though I could spend some time to make a vector version).

Comment: Also, check out http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ - it has a few magnifying glass icons out of the box and is a generally useful approach, even if you're not using bootstrap. In that case you would just adjust the `color` property.

Comment: Yeah, Font Awesome is incredible. You'd love it for something like this. It's supported in old IE browsers, too.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle with the numbers on this to get your color.

```
img.magnify:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(20deg);
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(20deg);
  -moz-filter: hue-rotate(20deg);
  -o-filter: hue-rotate(20deg);
  -ms-filter: hue-rotate(20deg);
}
```

[Found here](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/) - more options available

Comment: That's nice, but it support is lacking. Firefox can't do any filter as of now. (On a side note, it probably be more than rotating the hue to get from white to red.)

Comment: There's also saturation to adjust.  But I know the support is slim, just wanted to give you something in case you didnt find anything else