# How to change the color of an embeded SVG image

Tags: svg

I have an `SVG` image element in my code.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image id="svg_social-link" x="20" y="20" width="17" height="17" xlink:href="mail-dark.png" />
</svg>
```

The image `mail-dark.png` is "Black" in `color` now.
I need to change its `color`. For example say to "green".I have tried using `css` as

```
<style>
#svg_social-link { 
    fill: green;
}
</style>
```

But its not worked. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: PNG is not the same as SVG. SVG is a vector format and PNG is raster. For changing color of a PNG you can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css

Comment: Is it the only reason we cant change the color.? If the image is a jpeg is it possible ?

Comment: If all your SVG contains is an image, then there is no point in having an SVG in the first place.  Just use `mail-dark.png` directly in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, You can not change the background color in a SVG image, you could do it if the image is the HTML code (out of SVG).

However you could do it in SVG with a workaround, using a `rect` as background:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="17" height="17" id="bk_rect" style="fill:#800000;"/>
    <image id="svg_social-link" x="20" y="20" width="17" height="17" xlink:href="mail-dark.png" />
</svg>
```

You can set the bk color inline or modify it using JS or CSS

```
$('#bk_rect').css('fill', '#aaaaaa');
```

I created JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7dcnZ/1/ To show it

Comment: Is there any possible method to convert an image into corresponding SVG paths? (Then I can apply the fill color).

Comment: You can do it with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/), The exact command is "Trace Bitmap", Depending on the bitmap the resulting path could be more or less accurate.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Is there any way to do it through code using any api or something like that?

Comment: Inkscape can by extended with Python, It has an API, but I'm not familiar with it. You could take a look to: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/PythonEffectTutorial and http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Script_extensions