# Ways to make image hover

Tags: css

I have this image and I want to make it white by default and cyan by hover. Is there another way than to make 2 images, one white and one cyan?

[image]

Comment: If it has transparency (.png), then you could use `background-color` to it. Otherwise, it should be 2 images.

Comment: yes make only one image and than change position on hover

Comment: Very nice idea, @Siyah. I'll go with that if there's no better way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css might be of help.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя what do you mean change `position` on hover..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a PNG where the magnifying glass is transparent, then set the background color on the `img` tag in CSS:

```
img {
  background: steelblue;
}

img:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/jeqihuxo/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use sprites. Well, technically would not be two seperate images but one image which `background-position` is changed on hover. Your image is 36x48, so make a new image 72x48 with the non-hover version on the left side and the hover version on the right and move the background on hover.