# Change color of glyphicons in Bootstrap v2.3.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

is there any possibility to change the color of glyphicons from bootstrap v2.3.2 without the migration in bootstrap v3.x?
I use, for example, this class:

```
<i class="icon-edit"></i>
```

I would be happy, if you can help me.

Greets,

Comment: Glyphicons should simply inherit the color of their container

Comment: @MarcoMercuri, icons in BS2 are based on a PNG sprite, so the `color` attribute doesn't do much.

Comment: As far I know glyphicosn in that version are an sprite image so you need to change the image itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this will be very hard to achieve in that version of bootstrap.

I'd recommend using [Font Awsome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

> Font Awesome gives you scalable vector icons that can instantly be customized — size, color, drop shadow, and anything that can be done with the power of CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it makes sense to change the icons in font awesome without changing bootstrap v2.3.2 in v3.x

Comment: You don't even need to override the font-icon color. You can just create a class like `.red { color: red; }` and then apply that to the `<i></i>` tag or the parent element and it _should_ override the color. That's a cleaner method IMO. Untested.

Answer (score 5):

Glyphicons in Bootstrap 2 are based on a PNG sprite. The only options you have that I see are:

- changing the image itself and replacing references to it in Bootstrap's CSS
- resorting to very [exotic css features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css) to change an image's color, though I'm unsure if this will work for glyphicons

In short, you can't really. Black and white (`-white` versions) are your only options.

Comment: On behalf of those forced to work with legacy code – thank you for a comprehensive answer. This was surprisingly hard to find (*i.e.* took more than 1 Google search).