# how can I change the background of this image?

Tags: css, html

I tried webfilters to change the white background of this image looking at this:

[Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css)

Not sure if this is the way to change the whitebackground of this image:

[image: radiobutton]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZRrE.png

Is it possible to change this through css?

Comment: That image has no transparency... (opening quote from other question: "Given a transparent PNG...")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a png that has a transparent background - the one you are using has a white background.  For example.

```css
.red {background-color:red;}
.blue {background-color:blue;}
.green {background-color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="red"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/UAdT2Jd.png" /></div>
<div class="blue"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/UAdT2Jd.png" /></div>
<div class="green"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/UAdT2Jd.png" /></div>
```

If you do a search for radio button png you should be able to find a better one than the one I have used (as mine has some rough edges that are showing up)

Comment: where to get the transparent icons from?

Comment: I usually [google radio button png](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=radio+button+png&safe=active&bih=1032&espv=2&biw=1920&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=MPL2VOrFH6Xm7gacgYGwAg&ved=0CCAQsAQ#imgdii=_) and choose one I like then right click and save as

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change this through css?

No. If the image had some transparency, you could change the `background-color` (and/or `background-image`) of its parent element, like so:

```
<span class="thing"><img src="your-semi-transparent-image.png"></span>
```

And in the CSS:

```
.thing {
  background-color: aqua; 
  /* This will show through the transparent region of the image */
}
```