# How to ignore transparent pixels with background blend mode

Tags: css, css-filters, background-blend-mode

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56bgvga5/2/)

```
.goblin {
  background-image: url("https://gameartpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/06/goblin_featured.png");
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  background-blend-mode: normal;
}

.goblin:hover {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Notice how when you hover over the image, it is correctly applying the red tint to the goblin.  However, I only want the red to apply to the goblin, not the transparent pixels around him.  Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Here is a closely related [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197686/background-blend-mode-on-png-images).  I was not able to use this solution because the image used in this one was very basic and only had a single color. -webkit-mask-box-image does not work for more complex examples.

EDIT: Here is a pic of what I want it to look like:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBHDF.jpg

Comment: Why not using a simple filter over an img element? Is there any reason so you have to stick with blend mode?

Comment: I'm really unclear on what it is you are trying to achieve here? Do you have an example of the *expected result*?

Comment: What do you mean by "the transparent pixels around him" ?

Comment: The expected result is exactly what is in the jsfiddle EXCEPT there should be no red background around the goblin.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to hopefully make it a bit more clear what is going on

Comment: @Frondor, which filter would make the goblin have a red tint?

Comment: @Paulie_D I just added the expected image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [mask-image CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image). Its experimental but fairly well supported.

Here I've used the same image as both the mask and the background:

```css
.goblin {
  background-image: url("https://gameartpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/06/goblin_featured.png");
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("https://gameartpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/06/goblin_featured.png");
  -webkit-mask-mode: alpha;
  mask-image: url("https://gameartpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/06/goblin_featured.png");
  mask-mode: alpha;
}

.goblin:hover {
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="goblin"></div>
```

Comment: Earlier today, I was playing with webkit mask image and couldn't get it to work.  Your solution does exactly what I want, thanks!

Comment: As of today, look like you should replace `-webkit-mask-image` by `-webkit-mask-box-image`, not sure about the `mask-image` property