# How to put a color with opacity in CSS in an image?

Tags: html, css, image, colors

the image is square, but it has a circle in the middle, the rest of the square is transparent.
I'm using

```
opacity: 0.86
```

but what I would like is to set a color in front of the image. something like that

```
color: rgba (247, 172, 8, 0.86);
```

I want the image to be that color and with that opacity on the front. like adding a "layer with color"

[image]

Comment: I'm not totally clear on your desired effect. Please show what you've coded and what specifically goes wrong as compared with what you want. It may help to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want that when selecting the image (which is a white circle) it turns orange basically

Comment: You might have some success with [`max-box-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-box-image), like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280817/is-there-any-way-to-colorize-a-white-png-image-with-css-only), but browser support is currently pretty limited. If the circle is just plain white, I might suggest a pure CSS circle instead of a PNG.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on your problem and on the expected result

Comment: yes without images is impossible

Answer (score 0):

This will help your needs.

Hope it works

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(247, 172, 8, 0.86);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm showing the transparent part with color, but I want you to show me the circle only (which is white) with an orange hue

Comment: @IvanParedes i added some few chages. On stand by if anything else is needed

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the transparent PNG aspect of the question.

Comment: @IvanParedes sorry i dont get what you are looking for. What i understand from the question is that you want a circle overlaying an image. Can you ilustrate/explain further

Comment: @IvanParedes so you want two circles??

Comment: no. the image is only an example. imagine the logo of VISA

Comment: @IvanParedes ok, i can imagine the logo of visa. But theres no circles in it