# How to style a png icon with CSS?

Tags: css, image, png, styling

I have a PNG image that I'm using as an icon.  It's a slightly different take on a play button.  I know that when I used the font-awesome play button icon, I could do all sorts of things to that with CSS.

[image]

How do I make my png image icon stylable?  Do I need to convert it to a different file?

Comment: if you mean, shadows, color, stroke, then svg will be fine, else you only have the img tag to style

Comment: What styles were you thinking of? Image files generally aren't stylable but it depends on what you're trying to do as to whether there might be something.

Comment: How do you want to style it? E.g. apply a circle around? A shadow? Change the color of arrow?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I guess @sheriffderek is right here.  I need to figure out how to get it into an svg file

Comment: @KylePennell - I added some clearer examples for ya. Inkscape is a free vector drawing app. Might want to check that out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css for some options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If you want to target paths of an svg, and use standard CSS rules, it has to be an .svg vector file.

You can create them in a variety of programs. In Adobe Illustrator, you 'save-as' > 'svg' > note the bottom of that pane - see the svg code > copy it > past it somewhere smart.

The png is a bitmap and is just a square you can resize and turn and stuff.

### HTML

```
<div class="image-w bitmap-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="image-w svg-logo">
    <?php require('big-svg-thing.php')?>
        or...
    {{partial 'big-svg-thing'}}
</div>
```

If you use PHP or handelbars or htmlbars etc... just to keep the svg code out of your way.

### CSS ideas for you

With images that need to resize all the time... I put them in `.image-w` to control them and to compress their pixels for retina screen.

Attached is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/9Lmjhya7/) --- because the svg is super ugly/long code

Note that I added classes to the parts of the svg that I wanted to style

```
/* global / overall image styles */
.image-w img, .image-w svg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

svg path { /* good preset for svg / sets 'fill' to casdade like color */
    fill: currentColor;
}  

.bitmap-logo { /* things you might do with you bitmap */
    max-width: 200px;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    opacity: .2;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.svg-logo { /* svg */
    max-width: 300px;
}

.svg-box { /* parts of the svg */
    color: blue;
}

.svg-squigle {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: @KylePennell - feel free to mark it as the answer:   ; )