# change image existing color from one to another one

Tags: css

I have calendar image with I want to change to another color. I dont have photoshop to edit the color. Is it possible to change color with css?

[image]

I want to apply color to this `color: #26416c;`

Comment: Is that a font icon?

Comment: If your image is a `PNG`, you can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css

Comment: @ManojKumar I am using jquery datepicker so I cannot use font icon.

Comment: You don't need Photoshop to do such small image editing. You can use Paint.Net (WIndows) / GIMP (WIndows, Linux, Mac) and other [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-photoshop/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an image, you're limited to editing it with an image editor, or using what is currently experimental CSS technology by using the [filter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter):

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/v96I5.png" />
```

Comment: `-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(15deg) saturate(0.65) brightness(0.66);` seems to get awfully close to `#26416c`. I made the background that color, then tweaked the filters until I couldn't see the image any more.