# Simple way to change color of "special" special character

Tags: html, wordpress, colors, special-characters

Is it possible to change the color of this and other special characters?

```
<div style="color:red;">This text is red but the following symbol isn't: &#10006 </div>
```

Apparently, the symbol is actually an image. So that explains why it's immune to the color attribute. But is there a way of changing the color nonetheless?

I found this question [Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css) but the answer a) didn't work in my browser or b) required several lines of code. I wondered whether there might be a better alternative, since this should be a very common issue.

Comment: On [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguu1cgd/) the code works fine, and the 'X' is turned red. You might need to post a little more code for us to work out what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Huh... yes, it works for me, too. However, on my website, it doesn't.

I use Wordpress and the Tempera theme. If you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: Special characters usually are represented purely as text, rather than images. It sounds more like a problem specific to wordpress, and perhaps specific to the Tempera theme too. Consider double-checking with the Wordpress community themselves or asking/checking under the `wordpress` tag here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working perfectly. Use `&#10006;` instead of `&#10006` as HTML entity is not closed and might create style error.

To change color, use CSS color property.

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, while working in the fiddle, both codes don't work on my website.