# How change color of text and image before print with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a easy way and **css only** solution to style my page before print.

- I'm looking for chance color to black and white for text and image.
- I'm also looking for a way to change the scale of image to printer doesn't consume só much paper.

If some one points me out the css tags and how to use them would be awesome. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do not ask 2 unrelated questions as a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
@media print {
  body {
      font-size: 10pt;
      background-image: url(photo_with_white_background.jpg);
  }      
}
```

To manipulate images you can use filters

```
img {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);}
img {-webkit-filter: invert(100%); filter: invert(100%);}
```

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20933311/2827823

Comment: how can I change the color of the images ?