# CSS: changing image in div when hovering

Tags: html, css

The goal: to build two blocks which should change their background color, text color and icon when hovering.

The trouble: I have no problem with background and text, but I found some difficulties with icons. How can I edit my HTML or CSS to reach the goal?

Here are my code: https://jsfiddle.net/teyrq0ze/
and images that should be used when hovering: `http://i.imgur.com/8MqehqH.png`, `http://i.imgur.com/pNgIqxQ.png`.

Comment: You should edit your question and paste the relevant code here. External links eventually became unavailable and prevent prospect users with similar issue to benefit from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `filter` to image on hovering over the `divs`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #333;
}

#footerblurb {
  color: #fff;
}

#footerblurb-inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
}

#footerblurb .column1,
.column2 {
  float: left;
  display: table;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

#footerblurb .column1 {
  margin-right: 6px;
}

#footerblurb .column1:hover,
.column2:hover {
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}

#footerblurb .column1 img {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

#footerblurb .column2 img {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

#footerblurb .column1 span {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

#footerblurb .column2 span {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#footerblurb .column1:hover img,
#footerblurb .column2:hover img{
 -webkit-filter: invert(100%); 
 filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="footerblurb">
  <div id="footerblurb-inner">

    <div class="column1" onclick="location.href=''">
      <span><img class="previous" src="http://i.imgur.com/0tnecTN.png"></span>
      <span>text text text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2" onclick="location.href=''">
      <span>text text text</span>
      <span><img class="next" src="http://i.imgur.com/e86z3mD.png"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/teyrq0ze/2/) here**

you can use different filtering to give different colors.

For more information [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css)

Comment: Yes, I think so. But several people tried to help me, and I'm feeling a little comfortless choosing one "best" answer, all of them are good in own way. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Add an extra image and hide it by default. toggle its visibility on hover. Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz8cL42p/1/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #333;
}
#footerblurb {
  color: #fff;
}
#footerblurb-inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
}
#footerblurb .column1,
.column2 {
  float: left;
  display: table;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
#footerblurb .column1 {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
#footerblurb .column1:hover,
.column2:hover {
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}
#footerblurb .column1:hover img,
#footerblurb .column2:hover img {
  display: none;
}
#footerblurb .column1 img.hover,
#footerblurb .column2 img.hover {
  display: none;
}
#footerblurb .column1:hover img.hover,
#footerblurb .column2:hover img.hover {
  display: initial;
}
#footerblurb .column1 img {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#footerblurb .column2 img {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#footerblurb .column1 span {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#footerblurb .column2 span {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="footerblurb">
  <div id="footerblurb-inner">

    <div class="column1" onclick="location.href=''">
      <span><img class="previous" src="http://i.imgur.com/0tnecTN.png"><img class="previous hover" src="http://i.imgur.com/8MqehqH.png"></span>
      <span>text text text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2" onclick="location.href=''">
      <span>text text text</span>
      <span><img class="next" src="http://i.imgur.com/e86z3mD.png">
      <img class="next hover" src="http://i.imgur.com/pNgIqxQ.png"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

Use `background-image` and toggle the image source on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to use images for some reason. You could use an icon library like Font Awesome. Where you can easily change the colours as of your icons as they are treated as text, and are also very scalable.

```
.column1, .column2 {
  position:relative;
}
.column1:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f104";
  font-size:40px;
  position:absolute;
  left:70px;
  top:4px;
}
.column2:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  font-size:40px;
  position:absolute;
  left:70px;
  top:4px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teyrq0ze/3/)

Comment: Could you please note, should I add some files into my website folder, or adding CSS code like yours will be enough?

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/ you can either download the stylesheet, or enter your email address, and youll be sent an embed code to stick in to your head. Have a look in the get started and examples pages, in how you would use the icons.