# How to remove the white background of an image HTML-CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I have an image and the background is white. how can i remove the white background?
This is my code:
`<img src="Galactic empire.png">`

And this is my output:
[image]

Comment: You could do this in CSS but you really should be doing this in Photoshop, GIMP, or some other image editing software.

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801665/how-to-recolor-a-white-on-transparent-image-to-an-arbitrary-color-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a png image, it automatically eliminates the checkered background. Use another image or edit the current image in Adobe Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ether photoshop and have image without background or use site like [RemoveBg](https://www.remove.bg/), to do the same, Might Help:)

Comment: the problem is it only removes the background and i want all of the white squares to dissapier..

Comment: this site does the best possible using its algorithm but it doesn't provide the desired results in some cases then you need to Photoshop on your own to do the same.