# Background color over transparent PNG image in CSS

Tags: html, css, png, background-color

Is it actually possible to apply a background-color over a transparent PNG image in CSS ? Here's an example:

With CSS, turning this image

[image]

into this with a CSS code like `background-color: rgba(0,0,300,.5)`

[image]

All in full CSS (and HTML of course) ?

Thanks.

Comment: No , it is not possible to change colors like that. Do you want image to get changed on hover or what.

Comment: @AnmolSandal it is indeed possible with CSS filters.

Comment: Yes i have searched for it and got a solution. Thumbs up to your question , learned a new stuff

Comment: Not my question, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Any success in changing color? i am not getting the perfect match for it

Comment: the question is lacking what he has tried

Comment: I didn't try anything in CSS, as I didn't know any way to do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this effect using `background-color`, since a transparent background color applied to an overlying element will always effect the transparent parts of the PNG image too.

You need the [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) `hue-rotate()` (rotate the image color to violet) and `brightness()` (make the image darker):

```css
img {
  filter: hue-rotate(230deg) brightness(60%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png" />
```

See MDN for [more information about CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter). There is also a useful [article on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) for CSS filters.

Comment: Thanks. So, there's no real way to put a low-transparency color hover an image instead of changing the image's color (with hue-rotate) fully into another color (just as if you were using `background-color: rgba(0,300,0,.15)` ?

Comment: You can do that, but even if you apply this effect to an overlying element, you will always effect the transparent parts of the image too...

Comment: Oh well, that's sad. I thought of image mapping, but you can't apply a background-color on it either. :/ Marking it as the best answer.

Comment: are u looking to have a hover effect?

Comment: Not really, i'm looking for a way to apply a small green color over a transparent image without applying it on the transparent parts of it, like andreas said. No hover effect here.

Answer (score 4):

**Use CSS Filters**

From an article about [filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) by Chris Coyier:

> CSS Filters are a powerful tool that authors can use to achieve
>   varying visual effects (sort of like Photoshop filters for the
>   browser). The CSS `filter` property provides access to effects like
>   blur or color shifting on an element’s rendering before the element is
>   displayed.
>
> - blur()
> - brightness()
> - contrast()
> - drop-shadow()
> - grayscale()
> - hue-rotate()
> - invert()
> - opacity()
> - saturate()
> - sepia()

**Filter samples** (based on W3S)**:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    float: left; 
}

.blur {-webkit-filter: blur(4px);filter: blur(4px);}
.brightness {-webkit-filter: brightness(0.30);filter: brightness(0.30);}
.contrast {-webkit-filter: contrast(180%);filter: contrast(180%);}
.grayscale {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);filter: grayscale(100%);}
.huerotate {-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);filter: hue-rotate(180deg);}
.invert {-webkit-filter: invert(100%);filter: invert(100%);}
.opacity {-webkit-filter: opacity(50%);filter: opacity(50%);}
.saturate {-webkit-filter: saturate(7); filter: saturate(7);}
.sepia {-webkit-filter: sepia(100%);filter: sepia(100%);}
.shadow {-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px green);filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px green);}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The filter property is not supported in Internet Explorer, Edge 12, or Safari 5.1 and earlier.</p>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="blur" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="brightness" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="contrast" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="grayscale" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="huerotate" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="invert" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="opacity" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="saturate" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="sepia" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">
<img class="shadow" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png"  width="300" height="300">

</body>
</html>
```

**On Hover effect:**

```css
img:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(250deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPnsV.png" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can do it with a help of CSS filters.**

> "The CSS filter property provides access to effects like blur or color
>   shifting on an element's rendering before the element is displayed.
>   Filters are commonly used to adjust the rendering of an image, a
>   background, or a border."  
>   *– Chris Coyier*

Have look at these websites:

[CSS filter Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)
[Filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)

Answer (score -1):

You can't change color of the image from CSS as you wish. But you can do it to some extend using filters.

```
.saturate {-webkit-filter: saturate(3); filter: saturate(3);}
.grayscale {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);}
.contrast {-webkit-filter: contrast(160%); filter: contrast(160%);}
.brightness {-webkit-filter: brightness(0.25); filter: brightness(0.25);}
.blur {-webkit-filter: blur(3px); filter: blur(3px);}
.invert {-webkit-filter: invert(100%); filter: invert(100%);}
.sepia {-webkit-filter: sepia(100%); filter: sepia(100%);}
.huerotate {-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg); filter: hue-rotate(180deg);}
.rss.opacity {-webkit-filter: opacity(50%); filter: opacity(50%);}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kitcodes/ash8ok3j/1/)**

Please check this stackoverflow answers.
[Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css)

Comment: Dont use the copied answer @heshan from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css

Comment: read his comment properly @AnmolSandal

"Please check this stackoverflow answers. Change color of PNG image via CSS?"

Comment: @AnmolSandal please check "Please check this stackoverflow answers. Change color of PNG image via CSS?". you can see the reference. So please check full comment before you comment.

Comment: Yes i mean that link can also be provided in content section to help user if we don't have our answers. I think this is what comment box is for. @HeshanKit don't think that i am arrogant. I did the same mistake before this is what i am talking about. Don't copy answer , please mention in a comment. I don't think it's an issue to be raised about.

Comment: @AnmolSandal then its better to explain that mistake first place in first comment rather than pointing same reference I mentioned. Anyway I will add references as comments next time. Thanks