# Change .png color with CSS

Tags: html, css, png

So I have this image:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I change the gray line to be black using CSS only?

The image is a png file and I'd like to keep the white background.

Edit:  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css) is not a duplicate, because it changes the background too, which is not what I want.

Comment: the png you provided is not transparent. and you can consider a greyscale filter

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change **png** images. If you want to change lines for example on hover or another events you need to use **svg** icons.

Comment: You can, to an extent, change the appearance of PNGs with the CSS `filter` property, if you're willing to deal with the limited browser support profile.

Comment: @RwwL yes, i agree with you, but you can't change elements on the icon