# How to replace color of PNG image using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, png

I have an icon in a webpage:

```
<div class='icon-container'>
    <img src = "img/gavel3.png" class="gavel-icon" style='vertical-align:center;width:80px;'>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replace the black in this image with the color: `#2a4f6c` using CSS only.  I tried to replace the black with this color using Photoshop, and it looks awful and grainy.  Is a solution possible using pure CSS?

Image in question below.

[image]

Comment: you can't change color of an external image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your icon is a `png` image, so each pixel is defined separately to have its own color. There are no whole shapes that you can target with css and define a color, as you would for regular HTML elements.

However, there I a few things I would say:

1. I would have thought that it should be possible to change the color of this shape in photoshop without making it look any more grainy or pixelated than before.
2. I would suggest making this into an `svg`. This is a vector file format, so it generally has a smaller file size compared to pixel images, has completely sharp and defined edges, and can be scaled up to any size without reducing its quality. And, most importantly for you, it's very easy to change its color with CSS.
3. You could try using CSS filters to change the appearance of your `png`. Check out this stackoverflow question to see if it helps: [Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css)

As I've said, an `svg` would be my recommended option. I've created a code snippet below of what that would look like – you'll find your color `#2a4f6c` in the code, so just change that if you want the image to have a different color again..

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1360.6 1077.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1360.6 1077.2;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#2a4f6c;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M356.4,460l260.4-109.3l-21.8-51.8L334.6,408.1c-13,5.5-19.2,20.5-13.7,33.5l1.9,4.6
 C328.3,459.3,343.3,465.5,356.4,460z"/>
<rect x="614.5" y="239" transform="matrix(0.9059 -0.4236 0.4236 0.9059 -61.7804 311.7127)" class="st0" width="111.8" height="111.8"/>
<path class="st0" d="M706.2,197.3l-131.4,61.4c-3.7,1.7-8.1,0.1-9.9-3.6l-14.1-30.2c-1.7-3.7-0.1-8.1,3.6-9.9l131.4-61.4
 c3.7-1.7,8.1-0.1,9.9,3.6l14.1,30.2C711.5,191.1,709.9,195.5,706.2,197.3z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M786.4,375.5L655,436.9c-3.7,1.7-8.1,0.1-9.9-3.6L631,403.1c-1.7-3.7-0.1-8.1,3.6-9.9L766,331.8
 c3.7-1.7,8.1-0.1,9.9,3.6l14.1,30.2C791.7,369.3,790.1,373.8,786.4,375.5z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M907.2,521.7c1-2,1.5-4.2,1.5-6.5v-18.7c0-8.2-6.6-14.8-14.8-14.8H547.4c-8.2,0-14.8,6.6-14.8,14.8v18.7
 c0,2.3,0.6,4.5,1.5,6.5H907.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M941.8,589.8H499.5c-13.3,0-24.1-10.8-24.1-24.1v0c0-13.3,10.8-24.1,24.1-24.1h442.3
 c13.3,0,24.1,10.8,24.1,24.1v0C966,579,955.1,589.8,941.8,589.8z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I need!  But, was there a process by which you converted the img to svg?

Comment: I created a new adobe illustrator file. Then I loaded your image into it and traced over it using the tools in illustrator. Then I clicked `File > Save a Copy` and selected svg as the format. To get the code, I opened the svg with the code editor I use (dreamweaver) and pasted the content here!

Answer (score 25):

Use the image as mask and you can do it:

```css
.img {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  -webkit-mask:url("https://i.ibb.co/FhZb3Xs/CJcLK.png") center/contain;
          mask:url("https://i.ibb.co/FhZb3Xs/CJcLK.png") center/contain;
}

img {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="img" style="background:#2a4f6c"></div>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/FhZb3Xs/CJcLK.png" >
```

Answer (score 8):

> You can't change the image color directly in css. (svg, icons can be possible)
>   Use various filter to change color, change `hue-rotate` value in code to get various color;

```css
.gavel-icon{
  filter: saturate(500%) contrast(800%) brightness(500%) 
      invert(80%) sepia(50%) hue-rotate(120deg); 
}
```

Comment: This tool will generate the filter for you: https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/