# Mask image in WKWebView subject to CORS limitations

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

Following up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108133/colorize-black-on-transparent-background-via-css). I have a B&W PNG image in my iOS app's resources. I'm using it in a piece of generated HTML, which is displayed in a WKWebView:

```
[MyWebView loadHTMLString: TheHTML baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle.resourceURL];
```

When I designate the image as **the background**, it loads and displays as expected:

```
.x {
display:inline-block;
background-image:url(r.png);
width:24px;
height:24px;
}
```

When I designate the very same image **as the mask**, the element appears blank as if there's no mask:

```
.x {
display:inline-block;
-webkit-mask: url(r.png);
mask: url(r.png);
width:24px;
height:24px;
background-color:#000000;
}
```

If I save the content as an HTML file, place it into a Web folder along with CSS and the image, and load using mobile Safari, the mask works as expected. From that I conclude that the slyle itself is otherwise okay.

When I connect to WKWebView in the simulator with the Safari inspector, and then load the page, I get a CORS error message in the console:

> Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Should't files the the app resource folder count at the same origin as the HTML string? I have no problem loading JavaScript and other images from the resource folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted a trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996292/ios-wkwebview-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http/47000950):

```
[MyWebView.configuration.preferences setValue: @YES forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
```

This isn't exactly a duplicate because the other question deals with XHR. What's new in this one is the fact that `WKWebView` treats mask images in the filesystem differently than stylesheets, backgrounds, and scripts.

Tested on iOS 9..13.

UPDATE: throws an `NSUnknownKeyException` on iOS 8.x! Haven't reproduced it, but I'm seeing crash reports to that effect.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. For Cordova project I used it like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1novDT8dL9U-rPsJQmPncMcMZnOsBFB2u/view?usp=sharing)