# How to convert black image to red color image using CSS3 filter

Tags: css

I have this image:

[image: https://spa0001.alanvo.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/homepage_icon_1.png]

On this site: https://spa0001.alanvo.com/

**It's under Our Fuel Text**

In this `dev` I have added a class called `home-our-fuel` and I am trying convert that black image to red color image using cs3 filter:

```
.home-our-fuel { 
    filter:grayscale(1);
}

.home-our-fuel:hover {
    filter:grayscale(0);
    
}

.home-our-fuel a img:hover {
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
}
```

But it's not converting to red color.

Comment: Adding `grayscale` does not make sens... You are trying to add grey on a black image. which is totaly saturated of gray

Comment: @MaxiGui can you tell me the write way to do this?

Comment: You can use `filter: invert(21%) sepia(100%) saturate(7414%) hue-rotate(359deg) brightness(94%) contrast(117%);`  made by: [CSS filter Generator](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

Comment: @MaxiGui I am trying it

Comment: @MaxiGui It's almost working but first it's showing me pink color and then red.

Comment: use the link I posted in previous comment to adjust the color you wish. And did you remove your gray filters ?

Comment: @MaxiGui Yes remove the gray filters You may check on this page: https://spa0001.alanvo.com/

Comment: It seems to work fine

Comment: can you see pink color when you hover over the image?

Comment: for me its is red, but if you think that is not enought red change the color with the link I post above. I won't help more.

Comment: @MaxiGui Thanks a lot. You help me already :)

Comment: checj this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373740/8620333

Comment: I am sorry this question has been closed as many of the answers in the alleged duplicate question are old and/or not correct. Thank  you @Temani Afit for pointing to a use of mask and ....

Comment: ...thank you @MaxiGui for giving an answer here (though sadly in comments so some users might miss it) and for pointing to the CSS filter Generator.

Comment: @AHaworth I could not post answer as question was closed, So I answered using comment.

Comment: @MaxGui I am very glad you did, it's a great solution.

Answer (score -3):

I think your question can be resolve in this ticket [Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css).

If you want the red color image you can use  { filter: saturate(3); }

But in your case you want the image all is black. I think you can change it to a font icon. and you can use them like color for text in css :)

Comment: Well, I am using png black color image. I just want to convert it to red color image on hover.

Comment: Only CSS can't change the image png from black to red. I give you the easy way to resolve this is: 
- First you must use the svg image and change it to font-icon. May be you can use this website to do this: https://fontello.com/
- Seconds, this font-icon you can style them with CSS like a text style, just use {color: red} to change their color.
Hope this can help you resolve your problem