# Change color for img tag

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development. While learning, copying a website(https://buypeel.com/) I encountered a problem - changing color for img tag. Spent couple hours in dev tool to firgue out which css properties changed color of  but still couldn't firgue out. HTML class : home-featured. In my code I changed color by changing SVG color, however I don't know how to do it to img tag.

What I have: 
[image: What I have]

What I want it to be: 
[image: Final product]

Thank for reading.

Comment: Can you show us your html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that particular site (https://buypeel.com/), it does not change the color of those particular images. instead of that it just set the `opacity` as 0.4 in `home-featured` and  `img` classes.

With opacity:
[image]

Without opacity:
[image]

Comment: You're right, thank you very much. Somehow I missed it, silly me.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @KevinD. Never mind we all have these kind of issues while coding. happy to help you. :)

Comment: I have used the images in order to clear the idea. In that picture, there is no code to work with. If you say do not post images why the stack overflow gives such a feature. @Rob

Comment: You can use images to compliment your written text but not as a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

You can affect on an `img` tag. But you can take their approach - use `svg` tag. When you do that, you can set the color by changing the `fill` attribute, or by using css rule `fill: [your_color]` <sub>[[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes#Using_CSS)]</sub>

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1336.6 329" fill="gray" width="60"><path d="M0,11.1C0,5,5,0,11.1,0h123.4c19.7,0,37.4,2.7,52.9,8.2c15.5,5.5,28.7,13.2,39.5,23.3c10.8,10,19.1,22,24.9,36c5.8,13.9,8.7,29.4,8.7,46.3v0.9c0,19.1-3.5,35.9-10.3,50.3c-6.9,14.4-16.4,26.5-28.4,36.2c-12.1,9.7-26.2,17-42.3,21.9c-16.1,4.9-33.5,7.3-51.9,7.3H83.5c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v76.6c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H11.1C5,329,0,324.1,0,317.9V11.1z M129.7,165.9c18.2,0,32.3-4.8,42.3-14.3c10-9.6,15-21.4,15-35.5v-0.9c0-16.3-5.2-28.7-15.7-37.1c-10.5-8.5-24.8-12.7-43-12.7H83.5c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v78.4c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1H129.7z"></path><path d="M386.1,0h225.6c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H457.6c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v44.6c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h66.5c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.3c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1h-66.5c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v46.9c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h156.5c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H386.1c-6.1,0-11.1-5-11.1-11.1V11.1C375.1,5,380,0,386.1,0z"></path><path d="M1111.3,0h50.2c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v241.5c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h141.9c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v43.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1h-214.3c-6.1,0-11.1-5-11.1-11.1V11.1C1100.2,5,1105.2,0,1111.3,0z"></path><path d="M748.6,0h225.6c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H820.1c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v44.6c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h66.5c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.3c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1h-66.5c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v46.9c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h156.5c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H748.6c-6.1,0-11.1-5-11.1-11.1V11.1C737.6,5,742.5,0,748.6,0z"></path></svg>
```

Css

```css
svg path {
  fill: gray;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1336.6 329" fill="#161616" width="60"><path d="M0,11.1C0,5,5,0,11.1,0h123.4c19.7,0,37.4,2.7,52.9,8.2c15.5,5.5,28.7,13.2,39.5,23.3c10.8,10,19.1,22,24.9,36c5.8,13.9,8.7,29.4,8.7,46.3v0.9c0,19.1-3.5,35.9-10.3,50.3c-6.9,14.4-16.4,26.5-28.4,36.2c-12.1,9.7-26.2,17-42.3,21.9c-16.1,4.9-33.5,7.3-51.9,7.3H83.5c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v76.6c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H11.1C5,329,0,324.1,0,317.9V11.1z M129.7,165.9c18.2,0,32.3-4.8,42.3-14.3c10-9.6,15-21.4,15-35.5v-0.9c0-16.3-5.2-28.7-15.7-37.1c-10.5-8.5-24.8-12.7-43-12.7H83.5c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v78.4c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1H129.7z"></path><path d="M386.1,0h225.6c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H457.6c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v44.6c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h66.5c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.3c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1h-66.5c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v46.9c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h156.5c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H386.1c-6.1,0-11.1-5-11.1-11.1V11.1C375.1,5,380,0,386.1,0z"></path><path d="M1111.3,0h50.2c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v241.5c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h141.9c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v43.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1h-214.3c-6.1,0-11.1-5-11.1-11.1V11.1C1100.2,5,1105.2,0,1111.3,0z"></path><path d="M748.6,0h225.6c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H820.1c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v44.6c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h66.5c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.3c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1h-66.5c-6.1,0-11.1,5-11.1,11.1v46.9c0,6.1,5,11.1,11.1,11.1h156.5c6.1,0,11.1,5,11.1,11.1v42.2c0,6.1-5,11.1-11.1,11.1H748.6c-6.1,0-11.1-5-11.1-11.1V11.1C737.6,5,742.5,0,748.6,0z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did - changing fill for 4 li svg. However, in their code the first li img src returns an image rather than svg. That made me confused.

Comment: If you click on the link of img src. However it turns out that they used opacity. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bitmap images (png, jpg, gif), then you can not change the color by css.
But in your case (black pixels on white background) you can use the opacity attribute to lighten the dark pixels.

Try something like this on the image tag:

Opacity: 0.6

The value must be between 0.0 (completly transparent) and 1.0 (completly opaque).

Comment: Yes, they indeed used opacity. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use css filter property for this.If you have to convert your image to (grayscale type) then this will help you -

```
img{
   filter: grayscale(50%);
   }
```

Or You can also reduce opacity also -

```
img {
    filter: opacity(30%);
    }
```

Comment: Filters are very powerful but quite new to CSS. They are only supported by around 95% of the general Browser users according to the website "Can I use". Internet Explorer has no support at all (at least for this modern type of css-filters). The opacity-attribute is supported by IE and in total by about 99% of all users. Therefore the opacity attribute seems to be more robust to me.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. In this case, they used opacity instead.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website you are trying to copy. Instead of changing the color they just put down the opacity of the img.

```css
.test {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay73j.png" alt="What I have">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the two images given, i think changing opacity will solve your problem.

```
img {

opacity: 0.5;

}
```

if you want the color change at hover,

```
img:hover {

opacity: 1.0;

 }
```

you can set value from 0 to 1

1 => solid

0 => fully transparent

if you want to check about more changes in images using css (like greyscale,sepia and others) do check out this stack-overflow question,
[Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css)

hope it helps!