# Linear gradient across an image with transparency in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, image, linear-gradients

I've got a simple .PNG image, with a white shape and a transparent background. This is being created in .js.

```
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "Images/seed.png";
    img.classList.add("seed");
    document.getElementById("spiralDiv").appendChild(img);
```

I would like to add a linear gradient to this shape, changing the opacity of the shape. I have tried using the normal `background: linear-gradient(rgba ...` method, but this gives the transparent background of the image a linear gradient as well, and I just want the gradient to **apply to the shape only**. Perhaps using a mask will help?

[Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css) was helpful to change just the color of the shape, but I am not sure how to get it working with a gradient.

I can't just draw the shape with a gradient in the photoshop, as I would also like to alter the direction of the gradient within the javascript at runtime.

[Seed image with black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV8Vw.jpg)

[Seed image with transparency](https://pasteboard.co/Je1kgET.png)

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEtDE.jpg)

(Sorry can't post images yet)

Comment: can you share the seed.png ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Edited - see link above

Comment: the image you shared is not transparent

Comment: I shared it with a black background, as a transparent background showes up as white on imgur. The black portion is the transparent area. Apologies

Comment: share it here and it will be kept transaprent even if it's white, we need the PNG to answer

Comment: still not transparent https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc63w.png

Comment: Try this - https://pasteboard.co/Je1kgET.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the image as a mask then you can add background as coloration:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,transparent,orange);
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity:0; /* no need to show the original image, it will simply define the size */
}

body {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png"></div>
```

More simplified code in case you know the ratio of your image:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,transparent,orange);
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}


body {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

Also like this if you want the image to remain visible:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  position:relative;
}
.box::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,transparent,orange);
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png"></div>
```

And with the ratio trick

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(45deg,transparent,orange),
   url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/PNtkhqg/iii.png) center/contain no-repeat;
}
.box::after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

from your linked image, a possibility could be a mix of `filter` and `mix-blend-mode`:

possible example :

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #ff730f, #ff730f, #ffc69f, white) red;
  width: max-content;
}
div + div {background:linear-gradient(to   left, orange,gray,purple,gold,green,tomato,blue)}
img {
  display: block;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  filter: invert(100%);
}
body {display:flex}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8GlLI4B.png"></div>

<div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8GlLI4B.png"></div>
```