# Change search-icon color - input type="search"

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an 'Input' with type 'search'

```
<input class="border01" type="search">
```

This gives me an search icon in my searchbar. How can I change the color of the search icon?

[image]

The screenshot shows what is generated when giving an input the type 'search". The 'background-image' is the search-icon

Comment: Please post the full code. Demo is preferred to get a good answer.

Comment: The input tag is pretty much the whole code. I'm using cirrus.css from here: https://cirrus-ui.netlify.app/forms/inputs#types

Comment: in F12 (where you now made a screenshot) Edit that ``background-image`` **SVG** to include ``stroke="red"``, once you understand how its done make a new CSS rule for that ``background-image`` in your applications CSS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the color using the [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill) attribute of SVG. You can apply that on your  [`path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). I had to use [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception) for the class because it would have lower priority. I replaced it with id for CSS specificity.

```css
input#border01 {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill="red" opacity="0.45" d="M14.891,14.39l-0.5.5a0.355,0.355,0,0,1-.5,0L9.526,10.529a5.3,5.3,0,1,1,2.106-4.212,5.268,5.268,0,0,1-1.1,3.21l4.362,4.362A0.354,0.354,0,0,1,14.891,14.39ZM6.316,2.418a3.9,3.9,0,1,0,3.9,3.9A3.9,3.9,0,0,0,6.316,2.418Z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githack.com/Spiderpig86/Cirrus/master/dist/cirrus.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="border01" type="search">
```

Answer (score 1):

The image seems to be a data:image SVG. You might need to have a different SVG file and insert it only for the search input. You could do that like this:

```
input[type=search] {
    background-image: url("url to the other image");
}
```

Comment: Oh so 'data:image svg' cannot be changed? I have to add my own image there?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the original picture, this might help you:
[Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css)

In this case, the color of the original picture can be changed via filters.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants it done with JS

```js
let input = document.querySelector('[type="search"]'); // get <input type="search">
console.log(input); // verify you got the correct input
let svg = getComputedStyle(input).backgroundImage; // get current background-image
svg = svg.replace(/\\"/g,"'"); // replace all double quotes with single quotes
svg = svg.replace("d=",`fill='red' d=`); // inject fill attribute
input.style.backgroundImage = svg; // set style (overruling CSS!)
```