# How can we set tint html color for image?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom

I want to change my image color dynamically with HTML color codes or RGBA for png image.

```
<img  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQeSIKRkAOaco7-ho-0VMICMF7ZeF3LE21NsQ&usqp=CAU" alt="logo"></img>
```

How is this possible?

Comment: have you tried any codes? , share them

Comment: actually I am new for HTML,I am android developer.I have search solution but not working

Comment: try some codes, and share more details and codes, without them its difficult to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css)